# Dynamically changing embedded twitter timeline using PHP

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am working on a project that involves multiple football teams and information about them. I am trying to create a dynamic PHP page that displays data from each team like fixtures and twitter accounts. I have the twitter names of each team saved in the database and I am trying to add them into the embedded twitter URL using a PHP variable, however, I am not having much success.

Is this possible to do?

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="300" data-height="400" href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo $twitterURL;?>?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by <?php echo $TeamName; ?></a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks